# Java project unable to connect to database (access denied)

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to connect my Java project to a MySQL Database.

```
public class ConnectToDatabse {
Connection connection = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
     ConnectToDatabse dao = new ConnectToDatabse();
        dao.ReadDatabase();
}
    

public void ReadDatabase() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/DupliFinderConnection"+"user=root&password=MySQLTest");
        System.out.println("Connection successfull");
        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
    }
        
}
```

}

I am getting this output:
***Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'Username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)***

Comment: `inderConnection"+"user=r`... - this just makes `DupliFinderConnectionuser=root`. I think you want `DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost/DupliFinderConnection","root","MySQLTest");  `

Answer (score 0):

I assume [this](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-mysql-database-via-jdbc) might help you!!!

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
 
public class MySQLConnectExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    // creates three different Connection objects
    Connection conn1 = null;
    Connection conn2 = null;
    Connection conn3 = null;

    try {
        // connect way #1
        String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "secret";

        conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
        if (conn1 != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to the database test1");
        }

        // connect way #2
        String url2 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2?user=root&password=secret";
        conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url2);
        if (conn2 != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to the database test2");
        }

        // connect way #3
        String url3 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test3";
        Properties info = new Properties();
        info.put("user", "root");
        info.put("password", "secret");

        conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection(url3, info);
        if (conn3 != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to the database test3");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred. Maybe user/password is invalid");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}